# How to change nav ul link on page scroll in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the nav link color on page scroll in Bootstrap 5. I have created a fiddle to show the problem, which is linked to below:

https://jsfiddle.net/mfen723/8kvf0431/20/

I am using the following function to try to change the color of the nav links after scrolling:

```
const navUlScroll = document.querySelector('a.nav-link');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    if (window.scrollY >= 26) {
        navUlScroll.classList.add('ul.navbar-nav-scroll');
    } else if (window.scrollY < 56)
        navUlScroll.classList.remove('ul.navbar-nav-scroll');
});
```

When I inspect the nav links (after scrolling) with dev tools I can see that the `ul.navbar-nav-scroll` class is added to the nav links but this has no effect on the color. The class consists of the following CSS:

```
ul.navbar-nav-scroll .nav-link {
  color: var(--blue-accent-light) !important;
}
```

I have used the !important rule to override any previous styling but it's still not working. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you want `navUlScroll.classList.add('navbar-nav-scroll');`. `ul.navbar-nav-scroll` is not a class, it's a selector containing both an element name and a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace these strings:

```
const navUlScroll = document.querySelector('a.nav-link');

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            if (window.scrollY >= 26) {
                navUlScroll.classList.add('ul.navbar-nav-scroll');
            } else if (window.scrollY < 56)
                navUlScroll.classList.remove('ul.navbar-nav-scroll');
        });
```

on this:

```
const navUlScroll = document.querySelector('ul.navbar-nav');

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            if (window.scrollY >= 26) {
                navUlScroll.classList.add('navbar-nav-scroll');
            } else if (window.scrollY < 56)
                navUlScroll.classList.remove('navbar-nav-scroll');
        });
```

Here is a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/wpexpert/jwsp3noy/4/

Answer (score 1):

These small changes to your Fiddle should get your result.

[Live Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p7dxb/qb6zuxdt/2/)

- Use querySelectorAll to change all the link colours.
- From [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) your `ul.navbar-nav-scroll` in the CSS file selects all `ul` with the class `navbar-nav-scroll`.
- The given solution adds the class `navbar-nav-scroll` to the 'a' tags and the CSS selector is for `a.navbar-nav-scroll.nav-link` so applies to items that have both class names.

## JS

```js
const navUlScrolls = document.querySelectorAll('a.nav-link');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {

  for (const navUlScroll of navUlScrolls) {
    if (window.scrollY >= 26) {
      navUlScroll.classList.add('navbar-nav-scroll');
    } else if (window.scrollY < 56)
      navUlScroll.classList.remove('navbar-nav-scroll');
  }

});
```

### CSS

```
a.navbar-nav-scroll.nav-link   {
  color: var(--blue-accent-light);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The wrong class name and your CSS caused this bug.

In JS you add `ul.navbar-nav-scroll` class to anchor (`<a>`) element but actually `ul.navbar-nav-scroll` means that:

```
ul.navbar-nav-scroll // --> <ul class='navbar-nav-scroll' ...>
```

You shouldn't specify element type (ul.) when adding classList. Because it create a className like this  `<a class='ul.navbar-nav-scroll'..>`

Your fixed fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/07jonqf9/

And fixed snippets here:

```
const navUlScroll = document.querySelector('a.nav-link');

        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
            if (window.scrollY >= 26) {
                navUlScroll.classList.add('navbar-nav-scroll');
            } else if (window.scrollY < 56)
                navUlScroll.classList.remove('navbar-nav-scroll');
        });
```

```
a.navbar-nav-scroll  {
  color: var(--blue-accent-light) !important;
}
```